# Синдром Вахтера или вам шашечки или ехать...

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Да, я в курсе, что заголовок несколько провокационный, прошу прощения, за некоторую желтизну, просто хотелось обсудить важную тему, связанную с модерацией, конкретно с закрытием по "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях".

Это связано с этим моим вопросом: [Правильно делать приватные методы Java статическими или нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748372/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-java-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82). Сразу хотел уточнить дело не в самом вопросе (он для меня не особо важен, к тому же у меня достаточно репутации, чтобы сделать его конкурсным), дело в проблеме с закрытием потенциально полезных сайту вопросов, как основанных на мнениях. И я ни в коем разе не пытаюсь ни на кого жаловаться, это  проблема подхода, а не отдельных людей (поэтому без имен и ников).

Суть в следующем, когда вопрос был задан он за десять минут набрал 15 плюсов и 0 минусов, что говорит, что тема важная и интересная для Java программистов. Однако, один из пользователей выложил ссылку на вопрос в чате и предложил, что вопрос стоит закрыть, как основанный на мнениях, а не фактах и вопрос быстро получил 3 голоса на закрытие.

**Тут две проблемы:**

1. Получается мнение одного человека, первым, написавшим в чат, может оказаться решающим, если остальные не будут сами разбираться, эффект толпы вещь опасная (с этим вряд ли что-то получится делать, просто хотел порекомендовать быть внимательнее с ссылками в чате),
2. Часто неправильно понимают причину "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях", ну в русском SO не так много популярных вопросов, чтобы можно было закрывать все подряд.

Давайте посмотрим почему это причина не применима к данному вопросу?

1. Такой вопрос, уже существует в [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/should-private-helper-methods-be-static-if-they-can-be-static), где правила модерированния часто куда суровее, и его никто не закрывает,
2. Этот вопрос не аналогичен приведенному в чате примеру про вопрос на какой строчке ставить скобки, так как вопрос про скобки это исключительно вопрос стиля, в данном случае вполне проектирования/дизайна/ООП.
3. Этот вопрос может быть основан на знаниях, а не мнениях, так как я просил приводить цитаты известных теоретиков ООП и авторов.
4. На этот вопрос можно дать определенный ответ, например, большинство теоретиков ООП и Java придерживаются такого-то мнения (или банда четырех - такого-то мнения, а Барбара Лисков - такого-то и дальше пользователи сами решат кому верить). Конечно, не все программисты могут быть с этим согласны, однако даже вопрос [как преобразовать InputStream в String в Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446009/4318868) имеет более десятка ответов c разными плюсами и минусами (производительностью при разных размерах, краткостью кода и прочим), предлагаете его закрывать?  Аналогом данного вопроса будет "Является ли Stateful Singleton антипатерном?", с одной стороны все равно будут несогласные считающие такой Singleton отличным решением, с другой стороны, можно привести конкретные аргументы и цитаты, чтобы доказать свое мнение.
5. К сожалению, программирование весьма молодая и инженерная наука и теория того что правильно, что нет в проектировании и дизайне ПО, во многом основана на субъективизме, а не на научных исследованиях. Однако это не значит, что не стоит пытаться сделать ее чуть более научной.
6. Ну и в конце концов, какой смысл закрывать популярный и интересный вопрос исключительно потому, что формально он вроде попадает под какой-то критерий? Кому от этого станет хорошо? Он не вызывал холивар и флейм (основная причина того запрета на enSO), а популярных интересных вопросов на ruSO как раз мало. Тут вопрос - вам запрещать (выполнять формальные запреты, придуманные для защиты более посещаемого сайта) или все-таки ехать (развивать сайт)?

ИМХО, я против закрытия вопросов о программировании и проектировании ПО, даже если они могут иметь дискуссионные и неочевидно-спорные ответы. Какое мнение у вас?

**P.S.** И еще раз это не проблема конкретного вопроса или конкретных пользователях.

**P.P.S** Пусть не смущает, что пользователь с относительно низкой репутацией лезет в вопросы модерирования ruSO, на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4318868/viacheslav-vedenin) у меня репутация куда выше и получены почти все возможные привелегии и знаки за модерирование (в том числе, золотые).

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Лев Толстой в романе Анна Каренина, говорил, что все счастливые семьи похожи, а все несчастные -- несчастны по-разному. Тем не менее, КМК не бывает такого, что есть одна какая-то хорошая практика, единственно верная, на которой можно поставить галочку и вы сами об этом прямо пишете. И ладно, если бы у одного имярек теоретика было мнение одно, а у другого -- другое, а если просто в компании принят только такой вариант (причём, принят первый попавшийся, потому что аргументов "за" и "против" примерно поровну, чисто практически: не устраивать же войны остроконечников против тупоконечников?)

Comment: Ну, почему не может быть? Может кто-то откапает стайлгайд Oracle, в котором сказано, что делать надо именно так и никак иначе? С именованием переменных, классов и констант именно так вопрос и решили. Вопрос про паттерны/антипатерны тоже оффтопик? Они ведь тоже все спорные, можно по любому паттерну/антипатерну доказывать что он плох/хорош

Comment: Почему конструктивная дискуссия, где не обязательно будет явный победитель в результате, это война остроконечников против тупоконечников? Ну вот во времена Коперника геоцентрическая и гелиоцентрическая обе были лишь неподтвержденными гипотезами и по вашему диалог там был не нужен?

Comment: "Однако, один из пользователей выложил ссылку на вопрос в чате и предложил, что вопрос стоит закрыть" - а вот перевирать не стоит. Хотя уже поздно, люди купились...Пользователь показал ссылку в подтверждение того, что логика на сайте не всегда прослеживается. И что иногда оффтоп заходит очень далеко, а онтопик наоборот. Предложения, что вопрос стоит закрыть - не было

Comment: "мнение может оказаться решающим, если остальные не будут сами разбираться, эффект толпы вещь опасная" - как вы интересно всех обкакали. Все тупые значит, а вы Дартаньян? При такой подаче даже читать не хочется о проблеме. Странно, что **такую** позицию некоторые поддержали (в разрезе самого описываемого вопроса)

Comment: кстати, почти все ваши пункты почему не стоит закрывать - как раз попадают под пункт почему это сделать  **нужно**. Достаточно прочитать противоречие "На этот вопрос можно дать **определенный** ответ, например, большинство теоретиков ООП и Java придерживаются такого-то **мнения**"...то есть МНЕНИЕ и ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫЙ ответ  - вещи разные. Как раз из-за МНЕНИЙ, а не определенности он и не может иметь точного ответа....."вопрос про скобки это исключительно вопрос стиля, в данном случае вполне проектирования/дизайна/ООП." - правильно здесь вопрос **стиля** дизайна, то есть очередной не аргумент вовсе.

Comment: Приложите ссылку пожалуйста на "один из пользователей выложил ссылку на вопрос в чате и предложил, что вопрос стоит закрыть", не могу найти (вернее ссылка есть, но предложения закрыть нет).

Comment: Есть 3 голоса за закрытие (я предполагаю, что есть несколько голосов и за "оставить открытым" из очереди проверок, см. ответ Suvitruf). Вопрос не закрыт (да, его сейчас нельзя закрыть, пока идет конкурс, но скорее всего и потом его не закроют). В чем проблема? Всех заставить не голосовать за закрытие вопроса невозможно, да и не нужно.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с общим посылом -- "Il est interdit d’interdire"

Comment: эх, это наверное беда всего stack exchange. недавно даже удалился из биоинформатики из-за немыслимой бюрократии

Answer (score 18):

Видел этот вопрос в очереди, голосовал за "оставить открытым".

На самом деле, у нас в переводе упущено одно уточнение. В оригинале:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, **rather than facts, references, or
>   specific expertise**.

Если дискуссия основана на фактах и т.п, то с таким вопросом не должно быть проблем.

---

Второй аспект - постановка вопроса.

Например, "Что лучше для сервера?" - плохой вопрос.

"Что лучше для сервера для онлайн игры?" - не особо лучше.

А "Какая технология на сервере лучше для асинхронной игры с небольшим количеством людей?" уже лучше.

Я бы предложил перевод подправить.

Answer (score 8):

Я один из тех, кто проголосовал за закрытие обсуждаемого вопроса (может быть даже первый) именно по причине того, что нельзя однозначно доказать правильность или неправильность, так как критерий правильности не сформулирован очевидным образом. Опираться на предложения каких-либо авторов книг, пусть и именитых, нельзя, это всё равно будет всего лишь авторским мнением.

Единственное, что можно сказать точно: `static` не допускает использование данных экземпляра, а стало быть любая функция, которая их не использует в данный текущий момент может быть сделана таковой. Если же есть какой-то задел на будущее, где предполагается использовать данные экземпляра, то можно не добавлять `static` при создании метода, дабы не убирать его потом. Правильно это или нет? Однозначного ответа нет и быть не может. Но могут быть высказаны причины как за использование статического метода, так и против.

Популярность вопроса (количество голосов и просмотров) не является признаком того, что он подходит для формата SO. Есть тому яркий пример: [Как учить ребенка программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/105133/176217)

Вопрос о `InputStream` другого толка, он предполагает наличие некоторых входных данных и четких выходных данных. То, что таких способов много, не делает вопрос, предполагающим ответ, основанный на мнениях. Это не мнения — это подходы, позволяющие достичь одинаковой цели.

В оригинальном же вопросе на enSO ядро вопроса звучит не так  как в обсуждаемом на ruSO:

> Is there any particular reason to specify computeOne and computeMore as static methods - or any particular reason not to?

Здесь нет предложения дать *правильный* подход в ответе, а звучит просьба озвучить “pro” и “contra”, взвесив которые, каждый читатель сможет решить, что подходит ему лучше.

Comment: Послушайте, но ведь обсуждали уже не раз и вроде бы все согласились, что проектирование и архитектура ПО -- это такая область, где очень часто не может быть однозначно верного ответа. Скатываться в требования однозначно верных ответов, основанных на фактах, это значит отказаться от обсуждения важных вопросов.

Comment: @andreycha если вопрос можно переформулировать, а это можно сделать хотя бы даже с оглядкой на упомянутый дубликат с enSO, то это стоит сделать. А комментарий хорошо бы подкрепить ссылками на обсуждения, дабы не быть голословным.